# NodeJS read file into string without encoding like PHP file_get_contents

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, file, png

I'm trying to process image and pass image data from a NodeJS app to hit an API wrote in PHP. 
I use `fs.readFileSync` to read the image file (I'm using PNG here). The API only takes string as file content to upload. It seems like PHP file_get_contents doesn't have a specified encoding as I tried `mb_detect_encoding($fileContent)` and outputs false and the fileContents starts like `\x89PNG\r`.
I'm using Node v8 and it seems like i have to use some encoding to convert Buffer to string. I tried couple of encoding like base64, binary and the fileContent starts like `\xc2\x89PNG\r` or `\xef\xbf\xbdPNG\r`.
What is the equivalent of PHP file_get_contents in NodeJS? How can I get the right format of image data?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you meant file_get_contents. If I was mistaken, feel free to roll back the edit, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you want to read an image file using nodeJS and send the image as a string to an API which is built using PHP. Have you tried first encoding it to base64 and casting it as string ?

```
var fs = require('fs');
// read binary data
var png= fs.readFileSync(pathToImageFile);
// convert binary data to base64 encoded string
var imageString = new Buffer(png).toString('base64');
```

Then send the `imageString` as a string, hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah I have tried that but it doesn't work. I don't know much about PHP. I found that there's somewhere else on the same server of that API im trying to use hits the same file upload function and it simply uses get_file_contents function and seems the result is not encoded. When I tried couple of different encoding when reading the image in my nodejs app, the string will be started with something else other than png head '\x89NG'

Comment: have you tried using **utf8** encoding with readFileSync?
`var png= fs.readFileSync(pathToImageFile,'utf8');`